Prove that if $B(X_\infty)\subset (1+\varepsilon)B(X)$, then $(1-\varepsilon) B(X)\subset B(X_\infty)$ Bollobas 4.8
Having some difficulty with this question.
I've managed to reformulate this question into the above statement, but this hasn't helped. I've tried to show that $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ form an Auerbach System, but I was unable to. Honestly, I'm quite lost on what to do here, and any help is appreciated

Sorry, but I think that it is assumed that the $x_i$ are linearly independent

Sorry, it is not assumed that they are linearly independent, but it can be shown that if they are linearly dependent, then there exist $\lambda_i$ such that $|\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i x_i| > (1+ \epsilon) \max_{1\le i \le n} |\lambda_i|$ (just take \lambda_i = \lambda_j)

@geetha290krm I think the point is universal quantifier for $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$. For fixed $\lambda_k$ this is of course wrong.

Assume WLOG that $|\lambda_1|$ is maximal. For $2 \le i \le n$ let $\mu_i = -\lambda_i$, and $\mu_1 = \lambda_1$. Then again, $|\mu_1|$ is maximal, thus
$$
\left\| \sum_{i=1}^n \mu_i x_i \right\| \le (1+\varepsilon)\max_{1\le i \le n}|\mu_i| = (1+\varepsilon)|\mu_1| = (1+\varepsilon)|\lambda_1| 
$$
We have the following:
\begin{align*}
\left\|\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i x_i\right\| &= \left\|2\lambda_1 x_1  - \sum_{i=1}^n \mu_i x_i\right\| \ge \left|2 \|\lambda_1 x_1\| - \left\|\sum_{i=1}^n \mu_i x_i\right\|\right| \\
&= 2 |\lambda_1| - \left\|\sum_{i=1}^n \mu_i x_i\right\| \ge 2|\lambda_1| -(1+\varepsilon)|\lambda_1| = (1-\varepsilon)\max_{1 \le i \le n}|\lambda_i|
\end{align*}

Neat solution. (+)

Thanks, I didn't come up with it. grobmez on a math discord server did
